# How to pass python df to R df in Jupyter Notebook?

Tags: python, r

I am receiving an error when trying to send python df to R df in Jupyter Notebook.
There is data in this df.

```
# Prior Cell
df = pd.DataFrame(full_4)
```

```
%R -i df
```

My error is:
ValueError: The name cannot be an empty string

Answer (score 0):

First, I think you need making activate `r`, like:

```
from rpy2.robjects import r, pandas2ri

pandas2ri.activate()
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).